# Can you explain roles of swarm machine?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

In http://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-w-machine/

There are four machines:

1. Local, where swarm create will run
2. swarm-master
3. swarm-agent-00
4. swarm-agent-01

My understanding is swarm-master will control agents, but what is Local used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for generating the  discovery token using the Docker Swarm image.
That token is used when creating the swarm master.

> This discovery service associates a token with instances of the Docker Daemon running on each node. [Other discovery service backends such as etcd, consul, and zookeeper are available](https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/swarm/discovery/).

So the "local" machine is there to make sure the swarm manager discovers nodes. Its functions are:

- **register**: register a new node
- **watch**: callback method for the swarm manager
- **fetch**: fetch the list of entries

See [this introduction](http://www.slideshare.net/rajdeep/docker-swarm-introduction):

[image: architecture]